# Is Google provides Android Icons related to application?

Tags: android, icons

From where i have get Android icons in different colors like search, add new, Navigation etc...
Is there any website which provides freely or should but those icon? if so from where  i have to download/buy whats the process?

I need common icons (were mentioned above) for all android applications in different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 3 scenarios:

1. U can use some resources from the system's image directory directly.
   You have to point to `android.R.drawable`....(instead of
   `R.drawable.`... to get those list of images.
2. There will be some others with will be in
   `sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res\`...
3. If you can't get those images in these, search in net

Comment: Thank you @Naresh i have got enough icons from directory thank you v.much